# What is the point of the "Disturb the Remains?"

Tags: destiny

Somewhere on Earth, in a small cave, I found a strange dark object on the ground. When I approached the thing, it said "Disturb the Remains." After I pressed it (and waited couple of seconds), it started playing a very strange audio (I was unable to understand it). What is the point of this, and what exactly is it saying?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That spot where you find the cave was the original location of the infamous Loot Cave, a cave that would spawn endless amounts of enemies and allow you to grind for exp and drops.  After that was removed by Bungie in a mandatory update, another Loot Cave was added elsewhere.

You're probably referring to this spot:

The spot where you see the prompt to "disturb the remains" is merely an easter egg that refers to, at least according to this [source](http://gamerant.com/destiny-loot-cave-rahool-easter-egg/), "A reference to the Cryptarch present on the game’s Tower, and the man who sells or decodes the many Engrams players farmed in the now-defunct spawn point."

Comment: I was able to understand the million deaths part, but has anyone made sense of the reversed part?

Comment: Those are likely just background spectral screams, nothing more about it has been revealed or found out by players, besides the "million deaths for Master Raoul" part

Comment: There is no reversed part. Just "A million deaths are not enough for Master Rahool" repeated several times, with some background noise.

Comment: Those were good times... End of an era when they patched that cave...